# Objective-C class Inheritance

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, dao

I'd like to ask about a problem I'm facing with:
I've two classes, **Photo** and **RemotePhoto**, which represents photo shooted using phone camera and downloaded photo. **RemotePhoto** inherits from **Photo** because it needs to redefine same logic.

I save both photo types info into DB, in a table called **Photo**, because they share same details, and used a column as a flag to distinguish between them.
I use a DAO to get photo info from DB.

The question is:

How can I manage the fact that if a row refers to local photo should be mapped to *Photo* class and otherwise use *RemotePhoto* ? I thought at making such a distinction into DAO implementation, but I'd like to know if there are some drawbacks.
I also like to know if it's possibile to leverage some ObjectiveC feature to accomplish this tack in an elegant way (so, maybe, I can learn something new ;).

Finally I'm also interested in some different DB organization proposal if someone faced similar problem: until now I hadn't to save remote photo info on DB, so I'm in time to make DB schema updates :)!

Comment: You should take a look at how class clusters works in Objective-C: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using a protocol instead of inheritance. If your RemotePhoto class has to reimplement the login held in your Photo class then inheritance probably isn't the best solution :)

Make two classes : `LocalPhoto` and `RemotePhoto` that both are subclasses of `NSObject` and implement the `Photo` protocol. Have a method (or a PhotoFactory if you're feeling fancy) that will take your DAO and return `id <Photo>`. The rest of your app shouldn't need to care if it's a local or remote photo.

Answer (score 1):

if your classes are NSObjects, you can use isKindOfClass(RemotePhoto) to tell if the object is a RemotePhoto or not